# Phase of patterned image is incorrect on iOS 3.x

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I'm displaying my view background using patterned image.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg_tile.png"]];
```

The tile image is 1x512px big. 512px because according to Apple docs tile images should be a size of power of 2 for performance reasons. And after my profiling I found out that if I use an image that is not of power of 2, iOS is creating a backing store for that image (more memory consumption than using a power of 2 image).

Everything works fine on iOS 4 and 5 but not on iOS 3.

On iOS 3 the phase of the patterned image is not correct. It seems that it begins with bottom-left corner to draw the image instead of top-left corner as stated in Apple docs.

> By default, the phase of the returned color is 0, which causes the top-left corner of the image to be aligned with the drawing origin. To change the phase, make the color the current color and then use the CGContextSetPatternPhase function to change the phase.

I found a workaround:
Use actual size for tile images instead of power of 2. But with this I'm losing the memory benefit of a image with size of power of 2.

Does someone has noticed this behavior? How can I properly fix this issue on iOS 3?

Answer (score 0):

I have used background image from pattern and loaded a pvr image  that way you can have a small image but  IOS3 you'll need to get a pvr loader. PowerVR SDK but its its c++.